# Mac OSX JetBrains Gogland: delve debugging meet "could not launch process: could not fork/exec"

Tags: go, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, goland

I'm using JetBrains Gogland 1.0 EAP on Mac OS, everything works good, but debugging (based on delve) will raise the error

```
could not launch process: could not fork/exec
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Updated the anwser according to @Alexander's comment

The truth is Gogland is using its own dlv binary, not the one you installed (manually or from `brew install`), and its own dlv binary seems not certificated or could be outdated in Mac's keychain, then it will cause the error above each time we run it.

## To fix it:

### Install your own dlv

Installing it manually or using the brew both are ok [[official doc]](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/osx/install.md)  and please make sure your cert have been set correctly

### Setup gogland, point dlv path to your own dlv binary

#### Step 1

Invoke `Help | Edit Custom Properties…` and add new line there:

```
dlv.path=/path/to/custom/delve
```

#### Step 2

Restart and try to debug again, it should fix the issue.

Comment: 1. Gogland's dlv is a signed binary for sure.
2. `Copy your dlv into gogland's bin dir.` is harmful. It breaks the sign of the Gogland application itself and it breaks patch update. Do not do this.
3. To replace dlv executable you should invoke Help | Edit Custom Properties… and add new line there: `dlv.path=/path/to/custom/delve`.
4. Invalidates caches doesn't affect debugging.

Please update your answer according to these notes.

Comment: @AlexanderZolotov but I do meet this issue, I googled everywhere, all solutions don't work for me, finally  the steps above resolved my issue.  And  I have ran Gogland's dlv in a shell, it raised the same error, that let me ***guess*** gogland's dlv binary doesn't be signed correctly, and I used the words ***"seems not"*** in my answer.

Comment: It might be just outdated and badly works on the new OS versions. It happened before. It's ok to guess the binary not signed propertly. I believe the third step deserve downvoting, it breaks user's installation.

Comment: Another pool man may meet "outdated" either :P I will update my answer per your comments. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I still can't get used to Enter's behavior. This is cool to have the instruction so anyone could update dlv in Gogland. So thanks a lot. it just should not break anything ;)

Comment: Agree, *"It breaks the sign of the Gogland application itself and it breaks patch update. "* convince me, gogland may custom their own dlv binary. I've updated my answer,

Comment: Cool, thank you. Btw, restart is needed after updating custom properties

Comment: After trying this, it started giving `Error: unknown flag: --backend` error.

Comment: Not working for me. I have to degrade my go version to 1.10 to avoid the problem